# Identical Strings in PHP not matching

Tags: php, regex, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two strings (one from my database and another supplied by the user) and see if they match! The problem I'm having is that they don't seem to match - even though the strings seems to be **exactly** identical?

My PHP code is below:

```
public function Verify($pdo, $id, $token) {
    $prepsql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
    $prepsql->execute();
    $currentrow = $prepsql->fetch();
    $current = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $currentrow["token"]);
    echo '<p>'.var_dump($current).'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.var_dump($token).'</p>';
    $token = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $token);
    if ($current == null || $current = "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (strcmp($token, $current) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the webpage output:

```
  string(244) "CAAW4HRuZBuB4BACA7GffOAwLHgmLgMMLGQxDAw8IJDCwahZAh0S4wZAcP8Q9DmMwsDpBq7jFcH1EzUIsZBbhKov12utoYFQns0HhgB5xKLeDqtZBRqavaNjNSn7KAcObZAEcavQCRbGlVKZBArfDEHskBSR8qAoU543DVTZCOyHm5oYNDVafwHl0bAkc4jyIhh2YHEPaNpWGC0FhezsSidOgLjnfFq8CeLVxHH0nUZBMLgAZDZD"
<p></p>string(244) "CAAW4HRuZBuB4BACA7GffOAwLHgmLgMMLGQxDAw8IJDCwahZAh0S4wZAcP8Q9DmMwsDpBq7jFcH1EzUIsZBbhKov12utoYFQns0HhgB5xKLeDqtZBRqavaNjNSn7KAcObZAEcavQCRbGlVKZBArfDEHskBSR8qAoU543DVTZCOyHm5oYNDVafwHl0bAkc4jyIhh2YHEPaNpWGC0FhezsSidOgLjnfFq8CeLVxHH0nUZBMLgAZDZD"
<p></p><p>Not authenticated</p>
```

Not authenticated just means that this function is returning false...

What on earth am I doing wrong? As per advice given on other similar Stack Overflow answers, I've used the regex function to basically only keep alphanumeric characters but that has made no difference? It isn't a trimming issue either as that didn't work!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you place the "$token = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $token);" before you do the "echo '<p>'.var_dump($token).'</p>';"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
if ($current == null || $current = "") {
//                               ^ now `$current` is "", an empty string
```

You assign a new value to `$current`, an empty string.

You probably want something like:

```
if ($current == null || $current == "") {
//                               ^^ now you are comparing
```

Comment: Basic 3 equals principle ;-)

Comment: Oh my god! Argh didn't see that I missed that tiny equal sign! That's exasperating! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @ImranAhmed I've been there :-)

Comment: @ImranAhmed You'd be amazed as to what a `.` will do to someone's day too. Years ago, it took me the better part of 3/4 of an hour to find out that that's what messed up a piece of code I was working on ;-) and it didn't stand out like it does here => `.` neither.